# Changing test ads to real one

Tags: ios, admob

I'm almost ready to publish my first app to the App Store. I use AdMob banners and reward videos. I used test ID for both all the time as it said on AdMob website. But now I'm not sure about few things and I can't find direct answers anywhere.

1. Before sending app for review I should change test IDs to my personal. As far as I understand I can't test my app with real IDs before sending, even if I won't be clicking any ads. So, can't I test it few times to make sure real ads work? And do I need to do this? Can I be sure if test ads work flawlessly real ads will work as well?
2. After my app is published, should I change IDs to test ones again to continue working on my app?

I also've seen an option to enable test devices, but I constantly using different simulators and real devices to make sure app looks right on all of them. And it just not too convenient to list all of them on every page.

Answer (score 0):

If test ads were already shown successfully, I will only need to make sure you switch your TestAd IDs with your RealAd IDs correctly (No typos).

> Please note that test ads operate through the same channels as live ads. Being able to return a test ad ensures that your application is communicating properly with our network.

Source: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2993019?hl=en

And yes, I think you should switch back to TestAd IDs if you are reworking your app. Perhaps make a simple if/else statements to simplify the process of going back and forth between RealAd and TestAd.